# Background fetch never fires without Xcode

Tags: ios, background-fetch

Background fetch works when i use Xcode's background fetch simulation. But when device is not connected to Xcode, background fetch not calls for about many hours of testing.

I enabled capabilities, my app is not terminated. Any suggestions?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
    return true
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let request = WeatherRequest(url: weatherUrl(for: "city"))
    request.perform{result in
        // show data in view controller
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that is not executed?

Comment: Label not updates in view with new data.

Comment: Where do you store the data? How do you update the screen when you go in the foreground? Do you have [Data Protection](https://www.bipsync.com/blog/what-apple-doesnt-tell-you-about-background-fetch/) enabled? There are so many things that may cause the problem that is impossible to tell without any additional info. One thing you could do in order to verify that the system is calling the method is to set the badge of the app...

Comment: @Alladinian Oh thank you! I found, that my ui changes should be executed in DispatchQueue.main. After installing on physical device, background fetch happened after few hours.